# Get Store IDs associated to a particular CMS Page

Tags: cms, magento-1, store-view, store-id

Given I have a Page Object (`Mage_Cms_Model_Page`), how do I get its associated store id's? As an array is preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `$page->getStoreId()` which will return an array (it can return `null` on new instances which are not yet saved to the DB).

In the page's resource model `Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page` there is an `_afterLoad()` method which will get the associated store ID's from the `cms_page_store` table and set them to the model as `'store_id'` which you can get by calling `getStoreId()`.

Comment: Thank you, that's correct. I happened to be getting my page object from the page collection which doesn't execute the _afterLoad method.

Comment: I think I ran into something similar myself and posted it here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63581/saving-cms-block-page-from-collection-removes-store-ids

Answer (score 5):

You can use the resource model for cms/page to lookup the storeIds

```
Mage::getResourceModel('cms/page')->lookupStoreIds($cmsPageObject->getId());
```

Comment: This method also works.

Answer (score 3):

Hi Please try with resource model which is give the store id basic of

```
   $Store_ids= $page->getResource()->lookupStoreIds($page->getId());
print_r($Store_ids)
```

It give the array for store ids using fetchCol().

```
$select  = $adapter->select()
    ->from($this->getTable('cms/page_store'), 'store_id')
    ->where('page_id = ?',(int)$pageId);

return $adapter->fetchCol($select);
```

This every used full whenever you can get store id from collection of cms page